# Inner String array swap

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

I try to swap inner string array value with none additional array, stack...etc.
 
Example:

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
output= [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
```

My solution shows as below, but I think isn't the best solution. Can someone correct my code efficiency?

```
[python3]
class Solution:
    def inner_number(self, s):
        i=len(s)//2
        index=1
        while i < len(s):
            for j in range(i,index,-1):
                s[j-1],s[j]=s[j],s[j-1]
            i+=1
            index+=2
        return s
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future please tag your question with the language you are using; it will make it so that people can find your question easier

Answer (score 0):

```
def inner_swap(input):
    req_length = int(len(input)/2) if len(input) % 2 == 0 else int(len(input)/2)+1
    s1 = input[:req_length]
    s2 = input[req_length:]
    result = [None]*len(input)
    result[::2] = s1
    result[1::2] = s2
    return result


assert inner_swap([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [1, 3, 2, 4]
assert inner_swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
```

Comment: this case is failing for all the other test cases let's say `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: no it doesn't it gives output `[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`.  There was a small typo. that might have given the impression that it doesn't.

Comment: see for any odd length of list say `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` it is stil giving error. [link](https://ideone.com/QwYYY4)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
h = len(s)//2
res= []
if len(s)%2==1:
    res = [j for i in zip(s[:h],s[h:]) for j in i] + [s[-1]]
else:
    res = [j for i in zip(s[:h],s[h:]) for j in i]
print(res)
# output [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 9]
```

Comment: many thanks for your helping, zip function is a good solution.